# If an item has the effect "XXX per 5 secs" is the effect over 5 secs or is it exactly on 5 secs?

Tags: league-of-legends

This mostly comes from the effects like HP regen and MP regen, is the amount spread over 5 secs or after 5 sec exactly?

Answer (score 12):

It's averaged out over 5 seconds.  It's very easy to test: Go into game and buy a meki pendant to start, then use mana.

It goes up steadily, and NEVER jumps up by 7 every 5 seconds.

Comment: I think Masck is right, I've seen Health and Mana tick average per second when I was using items like Philospher Stone.

Comment: Yep, the gold on the philosopher stone is the same, it goes up 1 by one not 5 by 5

Comment: You will just notice that sometimes it sees to come up faster than normal. you can check it with the gold per 5 sec. each sec is 1 gold, sometimes you see 0.5 seconds per gold. But never jumps. Is like when you are watching the ms in a clock, they never jump, just run faster and faster.

Answer (score 4):

It's periodically. If you have an item that generates gold per 10, such as Heart of Gold or Kage's Lucky Pick, then you get more gold over time, not a sudden burst every 10 seconds. If you want to test this, then amass a large sum of money and go back to the base and buy a number of gold per 10 items and watch as your gold gain skyrockets. This applies to all other stats such as Health or Mana Regen, or runes for Energy gain. However, Force of Nature gives the 0.35% health every second on the dot.

Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Health_regeneration

Comment: Health regeneration (also known as Hp5 or health per 5 seconds) is a statistic that determines the amount of health that a champion regenerates over a five second period. Each champion starts with a different rate of base health regeneration. Health regeneration stacks additively. The actual healing effect from regeneration is applied every half-second, not every 5 seconds

Comment: Mana Regeneration (also known as Mp5 or mana per 5 seconds) is a statistic that determines the amount of mana that a champion regenerates over a five second period. Each champion starts with a certain rate of base mana regeneration. This statistic scales additively; meaning that each bonus point acquired directly affects the statistic. The player can also use Clarity (a summoner spell) to restore mana.
 In Dominion mode, mana regeneration is increased by 2% per 1% mana you are missing. (Twice the effect of  Chalice of Harmony)

Comment: adding for Aceofgods and for people who want a quick reference

Answer (score 3):

If you pay attention to the video, after 6 warmongs, Rumble ticks every second for Health Per 5 secs. They're small amounts and though the video is fast, they are still per minute. I don't know about gold or mana. I assume they might be the same.

Comment: Basically. The MP5, GP5, HP5 etc are calculate by SECOND. as the amount of the Rumble HP5 is huge, each second looks how it "jump" from a number to another, but the amount is calculate by ms and shows per second.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help? I don't know the video quality is a bit bad.

Comment: I don't know but I think that's mundo's passive and force of nature ticking. I can't tell how much life is passing by.

Answer (score 1):

> The actual healing effect from regeneration is applied every
>   half-second, not every 5 seconds.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Health_regeneration

Answer (score 1):

For health regen and mana regen items the effect is calculated every 0.5 seconds
so for example if you have a total of 30  health regen. every 0.5 seconds 3 health is added. which over a 5 second period accumulates to 30 health.

Then there are items like the Rod of Ages which adds x amount of mana/health every 60 seconds. but this effect is only applied once every 60 seconds and is not calculated or added per second

As a general rule: hp/mp regen, gp/5 and damage over time is calculated per 0.5 seconds.
anything else is added all at once like Rod of Ages.

```
Source:
- myself (loads of buying regen/gp5 items / 2000 games of experience)
- http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Health_regen
- http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Mana_regeneration
```

Answer (score -2):

It is five seconds exactly. If you look at your mana bar, it doesn't sit there and tick up instantly, it kinda just jumps.

The reason that this is done is because of the work it would take to turn an 13mp5 into a tick each second. Its more reliable to give it every 5 seconds, that way the pros can know the second they will have the mana to kill with.

Comment: What?  It is spread over 5 seconds, the game has lots of things that are decimalized and it simply rounds and keeps track of the difference.  For instance, what should your cooldown be on an ability with base cooldown of 18 seconds if your cooldown reduction is 20.5%?  Well 18*0.795 = 14.31 seconds.  The tooltip will never show 14.31 seconds but simply round the difference.  In actual game play, you'll notice that it isn't 14 seconds but not quite 15 seconds.  Computers don't care about decimal places...

Answer (score -3):

It generally means in games like league of legends that every 5 seconds the effect occurs, IE: 10 gold per 5 on Heart of Gold means that it adds an ADDITIONAL 10 gold generated for your character every 5 seconds on the 5 second mark.

Keep in mind this is in addition to the passive 13 gold generated every 10 seconds, which starts when Minions begin spawning 1 minute 30 seconds into the game.

Further information on gold generation can be found here: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Gold

Comment: That's not true for Gold income. The passive 13 gold per 10 seconds are equally divide over the 10 secs. Plus Heart of Gold does is a GP5/10 item, meaning it add 5 gold over 10 secs, not 10 gold over 5 secs.

Comment: I believe Ataraxy is right, the gold seems to come certain intervals but the HP/MP regen is divided over time.

Comment: @Butterball2012 Could you or +Ataraxey provide some proof ?

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if anyone has solved this yet. I think it's at the 5 sec mark. The amount you get back is not consistent in the game. At the 5 sec mark i've seen it jump.

Comment: I'd like proof!